# Swift: Replacing substring using regular expression not working

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I'm building a regular expression to detect if match the following string but its not working. Here is my code:

```
var str = "asdasdd.ASD98ASD09ASD098ASD098ADS908"
let commsRegex = "\\D[a-z]{7,}.[^a-zA-Z0-9]{28,}"

if (str.rangeOfString(commsRegex,options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil) {

         str = "itwork.yes"   
        }
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: try like this `"^[a-z]{7}\\.[A-Z0-9]{28}$"`

Comment: @LeoDabus this works great. Question if I asdasdd to add~sdd doesn't work what can modify to able to detect "and~sdd.ASD98ASD09ASD098ASD098ADS908" for example

Comment: Is ~ required to be at an specific place (middle of that first 7 chars group)`"[a-z]{3}~[a-z]{3}\\.[A-Z0-9]{28}$"` if not `"[a-z~]{7}\\.[A-Z0-9]{28}$"`

Answer (score 2):

Your reg-ex appears to be incorrect, particularly this part:

[ **^** a-zA-Z0-9]

Notice the bolded `^`, this means match only characters *not* in a-z A-Z and 0-9.  I suspect you want to remove that character from your regex.

Also, I'm not sure about the `\\D`, this will match any non-digit, but your string starts with 7 characters which seems to match the next part, perhaps that should be removed as well if you expect that string to match the regex.

Comment: Yep. Also, the failure to escape the `.` character (as shown by Leo) is also a problem. Also, I assume he included the `^` to try to match the start of the string, so it's not so much as "remove" the `^` as to just move it to the start of the pattern, before the `[` and `]`.